# Pandas data frame (df) groupby with user defined function that uses df row and column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-defined

I have created a dataframe (df) which stores below information, HS1 is the index.

```
HS1 HS2 EffNotional_UnMG
EUR 3   -10082.91381
USD 2   -36253.84938
USD 3   78693.86806
```

Now I want to apply two ierations on this dataframe: outer by HS1 and the inner by HS2 so as to get two dictionaries (already declared with default values) as below:
For EUR: {'2': 20000.00,'3':0} [Key 3 has 0 default value]
For USD: {'2': -36253.84938, '3':78693.86806}

I  used itertuple and get following output for the outer iteration:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
print (row)
```

> Pandas(Index='EUR', HS2=3, EffNotional_UnMG=-10082.913813053281)
>
> Pandas(Index='USD', HS2=2, EffNotional_UnMG=-36253.849384403635)
>
> Pandas(Index='USD', HS2=3, EffNotional_UnMG=78693.868057473315)

Can one guide on proceed with the inner iteration using itertuples.

Comment: Ignore AssetClass in the output.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe loop is not necessary, use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) +  [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) + [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.pivot('HS2','HS1','EffNotional_UnMG').fillna(0).to_dict()
```

Alternative solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) + [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.set_index(['HS2','HS1'])['EffNotional_UnMG'].unstack(fill_value=0).to_dict()
```

---

```
print (d)
{'EUR': {'2': 0.0, '3': -10082.91381}, 'USD': {'2': -36253.84938, '3': 78693.86806000001}}
```

Comment: I dont understand, can you create data with expected output and explain, why it does not work?

Comment: The itertuple solution would be still helpful. Shared solution is great. However the dictionary has a mandatory key as '1' which is required in later calculation along with other keys. How can we introduce the keys missed in pivot ? The addition of missing key (1 or 2 or 3) has to be dynamic. Many thanks. The formula used is                        Addon=sqrt(d['1']**2+d['2']**2+d['3']**2+1.4*d['1']*d['2']+1.4*d['2']*d['3']+0.6*d['1']*d['3'])

Comment: `pivot` is for adding `0` for all missing values. Without data is is really close give you nice answer - what you need ;)

Comment: I managed the missing part as :  d2.update((missing,0) for missing in set(lst).difference(d2)) where lst is a list containing 1,2 and 3 and d2 is the subdictionary for each key

Comment: Got the answer below for each currency                                                 for x,y in d.items():
    d2=y
    print (x)
    d2.update((missing,0) for missing in set(lst).difference(d2))
    print (d2)
    addon=sqrt(d2[1]**2+d2[2]**2+d2[3]**2+1.4*d2[1]*d2[2]+1.4*d2[2]*d2[3]+0.6*d2[1]*d2[3])
    print (addon)                                                                                                         EUR
{2: 0.0, 3: -10082.913813053281, 1: 0}
10082.913813053281
USD
{2: -36253.849384403635, 3: 78693.868057473315, 1: 0}
59269.9634637104